Trying to recover BTC after being in prison since it started
I had gotten BTC when it first started. I went to prison and lost everything. I did receive paperwork in the mail when I got them this is how long ago this was.
It wasn'tuch than but today this could changey life completely if I recover this.
Any help would be appreciated.
What do I do? Please lmk
